# Search component for WPF textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, search, textbox

I'm looking for a WPF textarea component that would allow the user to search inside it. Something similar to the notepad, but as a reusable component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly available as component, but MSDN has example code for [notepad application with search capability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972157.aspx) in WPF. I guess I can modify the code for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a normal TextBox for this unless you want extra features notepad doesn't have.

Use `int startIndex = textBox.Text.IndexOf(searchString)` to determine where the searchstring is located and `textBox.Select(startIndex, searchString.Length)` to select the text.
When you want to search for the next item keep track of the startIndex and use `startIndex = textBox.Text.IndexOf(searchString, startIndex + searchString.Length)` and use the select again.
Btw this works the same for the RichTextBox.

Edit: For a "multiline" textbox use: `<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" .../>`

Comment: There's much moer needed from searchable textarea than IndexOf. What about the search form itself? What about indicating how many results found? Of course I can implement it myself, but it's much better to use an existing reusable component.

Comment: You said you where looking for "a WPF textarea component that would allow you to search inside".... Not that you wanted a complete notepad "search window". Anyway you can use the link you posted, I don't know any other components...

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example and sourcecode [[here]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14716/A-User-Searchable-TextBox-RichTextBox-ListView-and)